# Where could Cage get alcohol on base?

Tags: edge-of-tomorrow

Around 1:11:57 into Edge of Tomorrow, Pvt/Maj Cage is on the dropship preparing for another day of combat when a fellow soldier asks him "have you been drinking?"

Given the precarious situation that Cage was in: waking up, branded a deserter, has nothing except the clothes on his back, couldn't even use a telephone, having to roll under a jeep to have any chance of doing something without eyeballs glued on him, why would anyone think he had been drinking? If he had beer/whatever on his breath, where did it come from?

I do not recall anyone else being drunk or drinking: the base was preparing to deploy to the front. It would be reasonable to assume that in such a situation the well-being of soldiers would be paramount. Commanders would not want their soldiers hung over in battle, and even in Britain, I would expect alcohol to be tightly controlled.

Comment: This is Europe, right? Nough said.

Comment: The troops had at least one deck of cards. I'm sure those weren't allowed either (since their sergeant made them eat them).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You think that a large deployment of troops would somehow be immune from the black market abundance of illicit material? Even in real life, drugs, alcohol, and illicit materials are abundant in field ops. It would not be unheard of or even unexpected for soldiers to have access to alcohol. Most of the soldiers at the base would be there voluntarily, and would not be patted down or strip searched. Put it this way, J Squads direct drill Sargent was against poker or card games and J Squad had a poker game going. Alcohol is just as easy to bring.

That said, Cage had plenty of opportunities to find illicit stashes of alcohol or drugs, both on base and off. From his various loops, he obviously didn't sleep that night between waking up at the DS kicks and the moving out, and he could have found alcohol on base or off.  He would have been back before deployment if he wanted. It was N+x day, where N is the number of interactions we have seen and X is the number we haven't. Cage has seen many iterations not shown in the film.

Comment: There are some personality types for whom making something forbidden actually attracts them to it! They get a thrill out of breaking the rules. My experience is mostly about smoking, I smoked for 29 years before giving up. All the people I know that are ex-smokers (I'm now an e-cig advocate) & there must be upwards of 100 of them, smoked before the legal age. Every. *Single. **One.***